# File upload control to upload PDF only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, format, html-helper

I got a file control like

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })

        </div>
```

I want it to allow only PDF format files, so in my model, its like

```
 [Display(Name = "Terms of Business")]
        [Required, FileExtensions(Extensions=".pdf", ErrorMessage="Incorrect file format")] 
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

However, the control still allows to upload documents of any format, why ?

What did I missed out ?

Comment: Your same code works fine for me. As Zafar mentioned in his answer you must have missed those js files. Plus you should also add `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try regular expressions.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.pdf|.PDF)$", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect file format")]
```

And make sure you have `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` referenced on the page for enabling client side validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code on button click event.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf")
        {
            Label1.Text = "File upload";
            string path = "images/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were missed **jquery validate js** files.

Make sure these code were in BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

And put this code into view layer:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```