# PDF Validation issue

Tags: asp.net, validation, c#-4.0

I have used regular expression validation like below

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="FileValidationPDF" runat="server" ControlToValidate="OFile"
ErrorMessage="Only PDF Allowed" ValidationExpression="([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.pdf)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It is not accepting files with name like MED1001855 (4).pdf or W-9Info+(1).pdf.

Please help !!!

Comment: look below stack-overflow related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325828/file-upload-control-to-upload-pdf-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a 3 step validation. First add `accept=".pdf"` tot the FileUpload Control. That will only show pdf files on the client pc. [Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp).

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="OFile" runat="server" accept=".pdf" />
```

Then the RegularExpressionValidator, since users could stil select `All files` in the above step and still select a different file type.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^.*\.(pdf|PDF)$" ID="FileValidationPDF" runat="server" ControlToValidate="OFile" ErrorMessage="Only PDF Allowed"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

And last always do server side validation

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OFile.HasFile)
    {
        if (OFile.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf")
        {
            //file is a PDF
        }
    }
}
```